# Flutter - Autocomplete function arguments in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

Is there a way in Intellij to autocomplete the argument `itemBuilder` to the default function?

That's what I want.

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {}
```

**Problem: How to autocomplete?**

[image: Problem Autocomplete]

Comment: I'm pretty sure no, but I think it's a good idea. I'd create a feature request in https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues because this is driven by the DartAnalyzer for all IDEs.

Comment: you can always type: `itemBuilder: _itemBuilder` and let the IDE create a "private" method named `_itemBuilder`

Comment: hi, was this ever implemented, I had a quick look on github issues but couldn't find anything